# Pause Materialized Views from Refreshing temporarily on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a table in Postgres that needs to have a column data type changed from float to numeric(10,2). However, there are 17 materialized views that have been created on this table by different owners, and I need to make sure that the materialized views are not refreshed while I make the change.

Is there a way to temporarily pause the materialized views from refreshing on Postgres, so that I can make the change to the table without breaking the views?

I am using AWS Aurora Postgresql v9.3

Comment: [I don't think it'll work.](https://dbfiddle.uk/2TpDr00Z) You'll get `ERROR:  cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule`. You might have to drop and recreate those views.

Comment: Why are you planning to change the data type? If the matview drop/recreate is problematic, you can instead add a trigger that will take care of rounding incoming data and `update your_table set your_column=your_column::numeric(10,2);` to round the existing data. Note that neither the data type change nor rounding this way will work if you have records with more than 8 digits before decimal point.